# C# XmlDocument validate different nodes with different schemas

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-parsing

I have a question about XML validation using the XmlDocument class, especially it's `.Validate()` method. The scenario is as follows:
I have a XML that looks like this:

```
<root>
   <Message id="1234">
      <Content1>
         <randomTag1>data</randomTag1>
         <randomTag2>data</randomTag2>
      </Content>
   </Message>
<root>
```

And the following two .xsd schemas

1:

```
<xs:schema id="root"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xs:element name="root" type="rType"/>
 <xs:complexType name="ThreeDSecure">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="Message" type="Message"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Message">
 <xs:choice maxOccurs="1">
  <xs:element name="Content1"/>
  <xs:element name="Content2"/>
 </xs:choice>
 <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

2:

```
<xs:schema id="Content1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xs:element name="Content1" type="c1Type"/>
  <xs:complexType name="c1Type">
   <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="randomTag1"/>
     <xs:element name="randomTag2"/>
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

The goal is, to be able to load the `XmlDocument` and add the two `XmlSchemaSet` to it, and then to be able to validate the whole document with the first .xsd, and then if the validation has no errors to validate the `<Content1>` node with the second .xsd

The code that I'm using is this one:

```
public bool Parse(string xmlString)
    {
        var doc = new XmlDocument();

        try { doc.LoadXml(xmlString); }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var errors = new List<string>();

        doc.Schemas.Add(/*load the first schema*/);
        doc.Validate((o, e) =>
                            {
                                if (e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error)
                                    errors.Add(e.Message);
                            });
        if(errors.Count > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var msgNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Message");

        var realMsg = msgNode.FirstChild;
        //we do this because we do not know if this node is "Content1" or "Content2" because for "Content2" there is a different .xsd schema
        doc.Schemas.Add(/*load the second schema using the realMsg.Name*/);

        errors.Clear();
        doc.Validate((o,e) => 
                            {
                                if(e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error)
                                    errors.Add(e.Message);
                            });
        if (errors.Count > 0)
        {

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

The code runs fine, but when I intentionally send a wrong XML format for the `<Content1>` tag, the second validation do not yields any errors.

It must be something I'm doing wrong, but I can't find what it is. 
Or maybe I would approach the problem in a different (not known for me) approach?

------- EDIT --------

I've tried the same xsd schemas, but I load them in a different `XmlDocument`, and it works fine:

```
public bool Parse(string xmlString)
    {
        var doc = new XmlDocument();

        try { doc.LoadXml(xmlString); }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var errors = new List<string>();

        doc.Schemas.Add(/*load the first schema*/);
        doc.Validate((o, e) =>
                            {
                                if (e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error)
                                    errors.Add(e.Message);
                            });
        if(errors.Count > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var msgNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Message");

        var realMsg = msgNode.FirstChild;
        var realDoc = new XmlDocument();
        realDoc.LoadXml(realMsg.OuterXml);
        //we do this because we do not know if this node is "Content1" or "Content2" because for "Content2" there is a different .xsd schema
        realDoc.Schemas.Add(/*load the second schema using the realMsg.Name*/);

        errors.Clear();
        realDoc.Validate((o,e) => 
                            {
                                if(e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error)
                                    errors.Add(e.Message);
                            });
        if (errors.Count > 0)
        {

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Is there any way I can avoid creating new `XmlDocument`?

Regards,
Julian

Comment: The 2nd schema has no criteria that will cause a failure.  The 1st has "required" and "maxOccurs".

Comment: Soo if I put a XML like this: `<Content1>
         <randomTag2>data</randomTag2>
      </Content>`, against the second schema, it will not provide error?

Comment: Use the XmlDocument Load() method and you will get an exception along with the schema check